# proving $\sum_{k=1}^∞ (S_k(x)-f(x)) $ Converges absolutley for $|x| < R$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Let  $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^∞ x^na_n $ with Convergence radius $R > 0$.

Define $S_k(x) = \sum_{n=1}^k x^na_n $.

I am trying to prove $\sum_{k=1}^∞ (S_k(x)-f(x)) $ Converges absolutley for $|x| < R$.

My work so far:

$$|S_k(x)-f(x)| = |\sum_{n=k+1}^∞a_nx^n|\le\sum_{n=k+1}^∞|a_nx^n|$$
So now I need to prove

$$\sum_{k=0}^∞\sum_{n=k+1}^∞|a_nx^n|$$

Converges, but was not able to go further.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty|a_nx^n|
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|a_nx^n|
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  n |a_nx^n| \, .
$$
Now show that this series has the same radius of convergence as the original series $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$.

The initial rearrangement is allowed because all terms are non-negative, in the sense that the first and the second series are simultaneously convergent or divergent, and in the case of convergence their value is equal.